# SQL query returns column with data from another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table Notices connected to tables Likes and Comments. When I return the notices for a user I also create columns: number_of_likes, number_of_comments and liked_by_me. The query is working correctly when the user making the query hasn't liked a notice (liked_by_me = 0) . But if they have (liked_by_me = 1) the value I get for number_of_likes is wrong and is the same as number_of_comments.

Example:

1)
- liked by me = false
- likes = 1
- comments = 5

Returned values:
- liked_by_me = 0
- number_of_likes = 1
- number_of_comments = 5

2)
- liked by me = true
- likes = 2
- comments = 5

Returned values:
- liked_by_me = 1
- number_of_likes = 5
- number_of_comments = 5

Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT notices.*
     , count(comment.id) as number_of_comments
     , count(like1.user_id) as number_of_likes
     , like2.user_id IS NOT NULL AS liked_by_me
     , boards.name as board_name
FROM notices
LEFT JOIN comments as comment
   ON (comment.notice_id = notices.id)
LEFT JOIN likes as like1
   ON (like1.notice_id = notices.id)
LEFT JOIN likes as like2
   ON (like2.notice_id = notices.id 
   AND like2.user_id = $1)
LEFT JOIN boards
   ON (boards.id = notices.board_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN board_users
   ON (board_users.board_id = notices.board_id)
WHERE board_users.user_id = $1
GROUP BY notices.id
       , boards.name
       , like2.user_id
       , userId
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have been on this for hours and I don't think I will be able to find the problem.

Thanks!

Solution:
Here is the working query

```
SELECT notices.*, 
(SELECT COUNT(user_id) from likes WHERE likes.notice_id = notices.id) AS number_of_likes, 
(SELECT user_id IS NOT NULL from likes WHERE likes.notice_id = notices.id AND likes.user_id = $1) AS liked_by_me, 
count(comments.id) as number_of_comments, boards.name as board_name
FROM notices LEFT JOIN comments ON (comments.notice_id = notices.id) 
LEFT JOIN boards ON (boards.id = notices.board_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN board_users ON (board_users.board_id = notices.board_id) 
WHERE board_users.user_id = $1 GROUP BY notices.id, boards.name", user);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You will have to use subeselects.**

Excellent article on this problem: **[The GROUPing pitfall](https://wikido.isoftdata.com/index.php/The_GROUPing_pitfall)**

**TL;DR:** Basically, you have to realize, that all your comments and likes are being multiplicated by one another. Try to display the result of the query without the group clause to see, that duplicate likes/comments are being counted.

EDIT: I didn't test this, but it's how the query might look:
(that is if user can only like one notice once, otherwise you would have to group current user likes too)

```
SELECT
    notices.*,
    comments.number_of_comments,
    likes.number_of_likes
    current_user_likes.user_id IS NOT NULL AS liked_by_me
    boards.name AS board_name
FROM notices

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS number_of_comments,
        notice_id
    FROM comments
    GROUP BY notice_id
) AS comments ON comments.notice_id = notices.id

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS number_of_likes,
        notice_id
    FROM likes
    GROUP BY notice_id
) AS likes ON likes.notice_id = notices.id

LEFT JOIN likes AS current_user_likes 
    ON current_user_likes.notice_id = notices.id 
        AND current_user_likes.user_id = $1
LEFT JOIN boards ON boards.id = notices.board_id

INNER JOIN board_users 
    ON board_users.board_id = notices.board_id
        AND board_users.user_id = $1;
```

Comment: Thank you! Your advice really helped me figure it out. So I tried using subselects in JOINs but they still required grouping and the colluding fields were still returning wrong values. I finally managed to get the right values by adding the subselects in the column declaration of the query.

Comment: I added what I meant as a SQL query. Not tested, but that's what I had in mind. I am not sure how performant would the subselects in columns query be.